# Black Box optimization of expectation value from probability distribution valued function

Tags: optimization, statistical-inference, quantum-computation

So the setup is the following:

I have a probability distribution valued function that maps each point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a probability density function $f_x$ on $\mathbb{R}$. (actually just a finite number of points, but since any such probability density functions can be written as a sum of $\delta$'s it is easier to just assume that $f_x$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$)

$$
F : \mathbb{R}^n \ni \vec{x} \mapsto (f_{\vec{x}}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+))
$$

I denote the expectation value of $f_\vec{x}$ by $E(\vec{x})$:

$$
E(\vec{x}) := \mathbb{E}(f_{\vec{x}}) = \int_\mathbb{R} y\, f_{\vec{x}} (y) \, \mathrm{d}y
$$

For each $\vec{x}$ the probability density $f_\vec{x}$ is a black box to me and I can only learn about it by sampling, which is expensive. $E(\vec{x})$ is a smooth function.

I wish to minimize $E(\vec{x})$ as a function of \vec{x}, with taking as few samples of $F(\vec{x})$ as possible. That means both: I want to try as few different $\vec{x}$ as possible and for each fixed $\vec{x}$ take as few samples as possible to estimate the expectation value.

It seems clear to me, that when I am far from the minimum in a region with big gradients I don't need to know $E(\vec{x})$ as well as when I am close to it, hence in these regions I can take less samples to decide in which direction to take the next optimisation steps. But what is the best optimizer for this kind of problem and what is a good strategy to decide on the number of samples to take from $f_{\vec{x}}$ (probably depending on an estimate of the variance in the previous step and step height in the previous step)?

Does anyone know what I need to search for, to find papers about this topic or knows other resources to look at?

**Some background**

This kind of problem frequently pops up in variational quantum algorithms, where the objective function is e.g. the energy expectation value of a given hamiltonian, $\vec{x}$ is some set of parameters to prepare a state and $f_\vec{x}$ represents the probabilities to find certain energy eigenstates of the hamiltonian in the state prepared with the parameters $\vec{x}$.

**edit**

A similar problem also occurs in machine learning where computing the cost function on all of the training data is computationally expensive and hence the cost function is only evaluated on a subset of the training data. This subset is made bigger, as we approach the minimum and the gradients get smaller. An example of this can be found in

http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2011/11/3226.pdf

Still my question stands, whether similar ideas have been proposed for other (gradient free) optimization algorithms.

Comment: What does it mean to minimize $E(x)$? If the density is given, this is a fixed number, nothing to minimize.

Comment: I wish to minimize $E(\vec{x})$ as a function of $\vec{x}$. Each $\vec{x}$ gives me a different density and I want to find the one with minimal expecation value. I will edit the question to make that clearer.